# Unique global symbol when linking with static libstd

Tags: c++, gcc, ldd, nm

I am building a shared library for another system. I wanted to make it linked as static, including all the libstdc and libstdc++, so I can use it as-is on another, older linux. However, when I linked it with below options:

```
/app/localstorage/dev/gcc/4.8.5/bin/g++ -fPIC -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -fno-gnu-unique -shared -Wl,-soname,libsgxstconnector.so -o libsgxstconnector.so one.o two.o -ldl -lrt
```

On the older linux I cannot load the library. The error message states

```
libsgxstconnector.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt8messagesIcE2idE
```

nm -a on the older server shows:

```
0000000000411c20 ? _ZNSt8messagesIcE2idE
```

this ? flag means that ld does not know it and this is probably the reason it cannot load. On my build linux it shows that it is a unique global symbol (flag u)

```
0000000000411c20 u _ZNSt8messagesIcE2idE
```

Hence the question: is there any possibility to eliminate this feature from my linked library? And are there any good practices to build linux-agnostic binaries? Maybe -fno-gnu-unique should be in different place?

ldd output is the same on all systems:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd23dac000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fed7ce12000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fed7cc09000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fed7c985000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fed7c5f1000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000030c4800000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fed7c3d3000)
```

Comment: Did you try not to integrate libstdc and libstdc++ into your own lib? It would probably make things easier, unless your lib uses recent features from libstdc and libstdc++ that are unlikely to exist in old systems.

Comment: -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ make these libs integrated. There is no dependency on them.

Comment: I found this: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=623280: "/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: undefined symbol: _ZNSt8messagesIcE2idE, version GLIBCXX_3.4", in 2011. What I don't manage to determine right now is whether the issue you are facing would occur if you were not integrating tge static standard libs but use those present on the old system at link time.